# How do I use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to grab data from another site?

Tags: asp-classic, serverxmlhttp

We have the folowing link: http://mvp.sos.state.ga.us/

Rather than create a db to replicate information that MVP page, we would like to use our own form, and then behind the scenes, send information to the site above to get results back using component called MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.

Unfortunately, I know nothing about this component or how to use it.

Would someone be kind enough to please give me pointers on how use our own ... to send information to the site above and get results back to our form?

We are basically trying to get users to enter first initial, lastname, county, date of birth.

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use this component for http-requests like "POST", "GET", "DELETE" etc.

**To create the object:**

```
<%
    Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
%>
```

**To send data using method "GET":**

```
<%
    objXML.Open "GET", "http://mvp.sos.state.ga.us/?some=querystring", false 
    objXML.Send ""
    Response.Write objXML.responseText
%>
```

Note that Open method has 3 parameters: *HTTP method, URL, asynchronous call*.

Note that Send method on a "GET" ignores its parameter.  (In this case we are passing parameters via the URL.)

**To send data using method "POST":**

```
<%
    objXML.Open "POST", "http://mvp.sos.state.ga.us/", false 
    objXML.Send "username=htbasaran&password=somepassword"
    Response.Write objXML.responseText
%>
```

Note for "POST" that Send method passes parameters in key-value pairs format like: *key1=value1&key2=value2&so=on...* or any other data like XML, JSON, etc.)

These are the basics of this component. If you need more information, you can check [microsoft's docs page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) out.

**An example code for getting form values and sending them using xmlhttp post method.**

```
<%
    ' getting form values
    my_uname = Request.Form("username")
    my_pword = Request.Form("password")

    ' creating object
    Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    ' sending variables to an external site
    objXML.Open "POST", "http://www.sitename.com/login.asp", false
    objXML.Send "username=" & my_uname & "&password=" & my_pword

    ' Assuming that successful login will return response "Ok"
    ' writing the result to the client.
    if objXML.responseText="Ok" then
        Response.Write "Login Successful!"
    else
        Response.Write "Login Failed!"
    end if
%>
```

Comment: This code is broken.  Parantheses should not be made when calling methods as statements.  Also the "POST" example should be setting the Content-Type header.

Comment: Given that I am trying to do this to get data from a site built with asp.net, is this still possible?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones at one point you are right but not at all. I am working with JScript Asp pages so this code is valid for JScript asp but VBScript. Anyway I will edit the answer and remove the parantheses.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh yes, still possible, because this component does not care which technology was used from the source-side, it only cares about the given results by the source.

Comment: it doesn't appear to work for me. Maybe I am using it incorrectly.

Can you please gobble up an example of posting form fields to that link and how to get results back from it?

Comment: I added a simple example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I guess my biggest issue is how to pass, say, lastname to the site I posted and get a value back to populate a form.

That has been the biggest issue so far. It would not have been that huge of an issue if it wasn't for that fact that that site is an asp.net site.

Comment: Ok! Now I checked your asp.net site and noticed that the site is not returning data we need to handle in our asp page. Its mandatory that the site we send request must response us with valuable data, not redirect us to an another page to get data! It appears that's nothing to do with the technology of the page but the technique :)

Comment: wow, thank you for the detailed answer. Saved me quite a bit of time! From here, I found this MSDN that some helpful samples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms766431(v=vs.85)

Comment: Can you help me on how to send a POST request passing a Basic authentication? I mean, using ASP VBScript 5.8

Comment: @franzisk, please ask your question in a detailed manner. I will be glad to try to assist you

Comment: @htbasaran don´t bother, I got it working now. Thanks